# Why my javascript doesn't load into Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

I am currently working on a Java Spring boot project, everything is worked but excepted the JavaScript code.
Here is the JS code:

```js
function handleFormSubmission(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form submitted");
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('contact-form'));

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/supportContact',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function () {
            swal({
                title: "CHÚC MỪNG BẠN",
                text: "Bạn đã đăng nhập thành công",
                icon: "success",
                buttons: {
                    awwYiss: {
                        text: "Tiếp tục",
                        value: "Tiếp tục",
                    },
                },
            }).then((value) => {
                if (value === "Tiếp tục") {
                    window.location.href = "/";
                }
            });
        },
    });
}
```

Here is the JSP file that calling the JS function

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
              <form id="contact-form" action="/supportContact" method="POST" onsubmit="handleFormSubmission(event)">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <fieldset>
                      <label for="name">Họ và tên</label>
                      <input type="name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Họ và tên..." autocomplete="on" required>
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <fieldset>
                      <label for="email">Địa chỉ Email</label>
                      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" pattern="[^ @]*@[^ @]*" placeholder="E-mail..." required="">
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <fieldset>
                      <label for="subject">Tiêu đề</label>
                      <input type="subject" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Tiêu đề..." autocomplete="on" >
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <fieldset>
                      <label for="message">Nội dung</label>
                      <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Nội dung"></textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <fieldset>
                      <button type="submit" id="form-submit" class="orange-button">Gửi thư</button>
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
```

And this is my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/supportContact")
    public String moreContact(
            @RequestParam(name = "name", required = false) String name,
            @RequestParam(name = "email", required = false) String email,
            @RequestParam(name = "subject", required = false) String subject,
            @RequestParam(name = "message", required = false) String message,
            Model model) {
        
        LienHeKhachHang khachHang = new LienHeKhachHang();
        khachHang.setTen_kh(name);
        khachHang.setEmail(email);
        khachHang.setChude(subject);
        khachHang.setNoidung(message);

        lienHeKhachHangDao.save(khachHang);
        return "home/contact";
```

When click the button It save all the data from `POST` request but doesn't load the JSscript. I've check by console.log and checking the directory when pressing F12, the directory is correct but the `console.log("Form submitted");` doesn't load as well as the JS script.

I have tried to console.log and checking the directory, the directory is working fine,excepted the console.log and other js function in handleFormSubmission function

Comment: Use an eventListener: `document.getEleemntById('contact-form').addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmission)` to have the event.preventDefault work

Comment: `onsubmit="handleFormSubmission(event)"` - you should really not use event handlers like that any more; this relies on the global `event` object, which you shouldn't do - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event My guess here is your `event.preventDefault();` probably already threw an error, but you didn't notice, because your console gets cleared after the form submits the "normal" way. Use proper jQuery event handler binding.